# Combine 2 lines in large text file using sed

Tags: unix, sed

How do I combine two specific adjacent lines in a large text file into one line using `sed`? For example I want to combine line numbered 2001891 and 2001892 into one line, and write it back to the file at the same line location (meaning line 2001893 and below will get shifted up)?

I've googled around for tutorials and manuals on `sed` but all are too cryptic to me (those `'2,3p;N;s/jam.l,21/.,lk;dczA[12]blahblah'` means what?)

Comment: “Some people, when confronted with a Unix problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use sed.’ Now they have two problems.” — The Unix-Haters Handbook http://simson.net/ref/ugh.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a `sed` guru, but I think you want:

```
sed -i '2001891N;s/\n//' filename
```

(Try it without `-i` on a test file before running it on important data, of course.)

```
$ cat a.dat
1
2
3
4
$ sed '2N;s/\n//' a.dat 
1
23
4
```

I tried the simpler `sed '2001891s/\n//'`, but it doesn't work when the pattern is `\n`.  For any other pattern (`sed '2001891s/a//'` for example), it seems to work.  It's too late in the night for me to think about it more, but I hope one of the `sed` gurus will explain what's going on with my simpler `sed` command.

Comment: To explain what's going on here: the `2001891` is the `address`; it tells `sed` to only operate on lines that match this pattern. `N` tells sed to append the next line into the `pattern space` (ie, the text it's currently working on). `;` starts a new command, and finally `s/\n//` strips out the newline character.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add an explanation, but you did before me.  Thanks!

Comment: The `s` and `y` commands of `sed` don't see the newline at the end of the pattern (or hold) space (only ones that appear before the end).

Comment: For efficiency this should be written `sed -i '2001891{N;s/\n//}' file` otherwise the substitute command is being invoked needlessly for all the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==2001891{printf $0;getline;print;next}1' file > temp;mv temp file
```

OR

```
$ awk '{printf (NR==2001891)?$0:$0"\n"}' file  > temp;mv temp file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can do some simple magic using cat, file redirection, and nl command.